# Creating a windows+mac+ios+android game, simplest way?

Tags: android, ios

I am looking at creating a new game with a few people, that I want to run on iphone, ipad, android devices, and as a windows and mac game.  Ideally, I would like to use the development platform that keeps the amount of specific code to each platform to a minimum.  The closest I have been able to find is Airplay SDK, which allows compilation for multiple mobile platforms.  What it lacks, however, is the ability to compile as a windows or mac application.  Apparently, you can compile for windows, but it is only a beta feature that will produce a product that won't run on all windows machines.

I was hoping for an answer to two questions:

1. Is there a better option for me than Airplay SDK?  If I had to reduce the number of platforms I'd develop for, I could go to no fewer than just iOS and windows - which are probably two of the hardest to simultaneously satisfy (programming language is not very important to me.  I have used a number of languages, and am comfortable with learning a new one if required)
2. How do other companies typically handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) might be a good solution for you!

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at [Unity](http://unity3d.com/unity/publishing/) if you're looking to reuse a codebase across those platforms. If you decide to roll your own solution have a look at the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depends very much on the game type, from my personal experience, games usually take up enough resources to make you write the code in native languages(especially for mobile devices, where the resources are so limited). If you use OpenGL, you could recycle a good amount of code on some of the platforms you mentioned which makes porting a lot easier. I personally would go for porting it on all platforms you mentioned, maybe it sounds crazy, but I had lots of trouble with some(openplug, adobe iphone packager,airplay) SDKs that promised to be super duper fast and easy to use/learn...but weren't.

Comment: I found the openplug to be pretty decent in creation of native apps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Java with OpenGL.
Java runs on everything.
However, it would take more work to write all the code.